# Disable automatic Date parsing in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

Having just upgraded to a newer version of HtmlUnit (2.4), I've noticed certain tests are failing when comparing the output of `asText`. Looking into the differences, this is because dates (present on the page in the format 11/06/2010 00:00z) are being altered in the output to read 2010-06-11.

Has anybody else encountered this, and can anybody advise how to turn off this (seemingly undocumented) feature. It seems to take place when reading in the document - I can side by side compare a version of the page with format dd/mm/YYYY and a `DomText` object reading YYYY-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be one of what locale settings HtmlUnit was reporting to the server, which was using this to determine the date formatting. Setting a default locale on the server solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

please use 2.8-snapshot from [here](http://build.canoo.com/htmlunit/artifacts), and advise.